# Как оставаться авторизованным vk api?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой авторизации десктоп приложений vk api.
Не могу разобраться как мне сохранять пользователя авторизованным в приложении, например как в программе Meredian player. Думал что он хранит пароль , оказалось это не так(в окне логна написано что мередиан не хранит пароли). А даже если и хранить пароль то не понятно как провести такую авторизацию без участия пользователя. Как составить запрос(в справке я не нашел). Заранее благодарен всем кто поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При авторизации запрашивайте разрешение на доступ в любое время.
    scope=offline

https://vk.com/dev/permissions